# NoReverseMatch at /<url>/

Tags: python, django

NoReverseMatch at `/<url>/`

i am trying to redirect my view to a url with get request parameter i am getting the above error,

Views:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('corporate_contribution/?event_id=',args=(event_id, )))
```

url:

```
url(r'^corporate_contribution/$','corporate_contribution', name='corporate_contribution'),
```

I am new to Django, please let me know if i am doing something wrong.

Comment: You cannot pass arguments as GET in the URL like that. You might want to use "return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('corporate_contribution', kwargs={'event_id':e.id})" or "HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('corporate_contribution', args=(e.id,)))"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View parameters and the query string are not the same thing. The `args` and `kwargs` in the reverse function are the arguments that get passed to your view function. The query string, that is the parameters after the `?` in your url, is parsed into the `request.GET` dictionary.

A simple solution would be to just append your query string to the url:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('%s?event_id=%s' % (reverse('corporate_contribution'), event_id))
```

Another way, which is the method that is frequently used, is to capture part of the url and use it as an argument to your view:

urls.py:

```
url(r^corporate_contribution/(?P<event_id>[\d]+)/$, 'corporate_contribution', name='corporate_contribution')
```

views.py:

```
def corporate_contribution(request, event_id):
    ...

def other_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('corporate_contribution',args=(event_id,)))
```

This will ensure that your view always gets an `event_id` passed. Note that the argument passed to the `reverse` function is the name of the url (defined by `name='...'`), not the actual url itself, so it definitely should not contain a slash. This is so that you can change the url itself without breaking your code, as the url will be changed everywhere.